# How do I transfer a dictionary with transferUserInfo to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I am trying to put a part of my Apple Watch app behind a paywall. For that, the iOS app automatically creates a dictionary with a true/false value, whether the content is purchases of not. The problem is, is no matter how I try, I cannot pass it to the Watch.

Here is my iOS **ViewController**:

```swift
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    //The dictionary to be passed to the Watch
    var dictionaryToPass = ["product1": 0, "product2": 0]
    
    
    //This will run, if the connection is successfully completed.
    //BUG: After '.activate()'-ing the session, this function successfully runs in the '.activated' state.
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print("WCSession - activationDidCompleteWith:", activationState, "and error code:", error as Any)
        switch activationState {
            case .activated:
                print("WCSession - activationDidCompleteWith .activated")
                //session.transferUserInfo(dictionaryToPass)
            case .inactive:
            print("WCSession - activationDidCompleteWith .inactive")
            case .notActivated:
            print("WCSession - activationDidCompleteWith .notActivated")
            default:
                print("WCSession - activationDidCompleteWith: something other ")
                break
            }
    }
    
    
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("WCSession - sessionDidBecomeInactive")
    }
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("WCSession - sessionDidDeactivate")
    }
    
    
    //Pushing the button on the iOS storyboard will attempt iOS-watchOS connection.
    @IBAction func tuiButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let session = WCSession.default
        if session.isReachable {
            session.transferUserInfo(dictionaryToPass)
        } else if WCSession.isSupported() {
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func sendmButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let session = WCSession.default
        if session.isReachable {
            session.sendMessage(dictionaryToPass, replyHandler: { reply in
                print(reply)
            }, errorHandler: nil)
        } else if WCSession.isSupported() {
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

And that's what I have on the watchOS's **Interface Controller**:

```swift
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {
    
    //The text label on the Watch Storyboard. Helps with debugging.
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print("watchOS - activationDidCompleteWith:", activationState)
    }
    
    
    //Whatever arrives, it will get printed to the console as well as the 'helloLabel' will be changed to help the debugging progress.
    //BUG: This is the part, that never gets run, even tough the WCSession activated successfully.
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        print("watchOS - didReceiveUserInfo", userInfo)
        helloLabel.setText("didReceiveUserInfo")
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print("watchOS - didReceiveMessage", message)
        helloLabel.setText("didReceiveMessage")
    }
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        replyHandler(["does it work?": "yes sir"])
        print("watchOS - didReceiveMessage", message)
        helloLabel.setText("didReceiveMessage")
    }
    
    
    //Setting the Interface Controller as WCSession Delegate
    private var session: WCSession = .default
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
    
    
    //Activating the session on the watchOS side as well.
    override func willActivate() {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
                let session = WCSession.default
                session.delegate = self
                session.activate()
            }
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the watchOS simulator that was buggy. Quite a pity one from Apple.

> **Further reading on Apple's forum:** https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127460

If anyone else is in the same shoes, I recommend running the code on a physical device, it works perfectly there. The final working code can be found [here](https://github.com/mrkbrts/WCSession) if anyone from Google results is looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

After looking at you code I have noticed two main issues:

1. You are not setting your `InterfaceController` as a `WCSession` delegate. The connection needs to be activated from both ends.

```swift
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    private var session: WCSession = .default
    
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }

}
```

2. To be able to receive a message from the counterpart device, you need to implement the [session(_:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615677-session) method. Add these methods to your `InterfaceController`:

```swift
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    print("watchOS - didReceiveMessage", message)
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
    replyHandler(["does it work?": "yes sir"])
    print("watchOS - didReceiveMessage", message)
}
```

As you can see, I have also implemented the second funciton that can respond with a `replyHandler` by calling it a passing some data. This can be useful while debugging.

Update both your button action and a `sendMessage` call. No need to reactivate a connection it the device is already reachable, also pass a reply handle to make sure watch gives back the data.

```swift
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if session.isReachable {
        session.sendMessage(watchInAppPurchases, replyHandler: { reply in
            print(reply)
        }, errorHandler: nil)
    } else if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}
```

#### Initial Answer

Do not attempt to sync the data directly after calling `activate()` since there is no guarantee that the connection is already established. Documentation clearly states that:

> This method executes asynchronously and calls the session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:) method of your delegate object upon completion.

Since you do set `self` as a delegate, try to move the `transferUserInfo` call to the `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)` implementation.

```swift
func session(
    _ session: WCSession,
    activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
    error: Error?
) {
    switch activationState {
    case .activated:
        session.transferUserInfo(watchInAppPurchases)
    default:
        // handle other states
        break 
    }
}
```

Also, when working with Swift make sure to restrain from using `CapitalizedCamelCase` names for properties, functions etc. Only use this notation for types. I have converted the original `WatchInAppPurchases` to `watchInAppPurchases` in the code sample above.

If your call to `transferUserInfo` still does not work, try to call the [sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage) instead

```swift
switch activationState {
case .activated:
    session.sendMessage(watchInAppPurchases, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
default:
    // handle other states
    break 
}
```

and monitor the [session(_:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615677-session) in you watch extension for any incoming messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing. It does get to the `.activated` state on the iOS side, but nothing happens on the Watch side neither in the `session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo` nor in the `session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith`.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check out the alternate solution

Comment: I have implemented this `func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print(message)
        print("didReceiveMessage has run")
    }` to the *InterfaceController* on the Watch but still nothing gets printed to the Console. I'm running this on my psychical devices and as XCode does not let me to run the iOS and watchOS app to the same time, I'm only running the watchOS one to be able to monitor the Console. However, I don't think this should influence the success of the `WCSession`.

Comment: The original idea to use the `transferUserInfo` instead of the `sendMessage` was that I'm transferring In-App Purchase data, and in the documentation Apple states, that the `transferUserInfo ` is guaranteed to get either delivered or queued for later delivery. Seems like neither of them are working though.

Comment: And are you sure you are setting a delegate to `WCSession` on WatchExtension as well? Have you tries sending any data the other way, from watch to phone?

Comment: Also, debugging by printing to the console might not be the best idea, try saving the received data to userdefaults and update UI in some way to indicate current values of the purchases dict.

Comment: Literally no clue what's going wrong. Read lot of documentation, tutorials, StackOverflow answers and I implement the code accordingly. I will attach a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mrkbrts/WCSession) about it. Thank you for your time though!

Comment: I have solved the issue, let me update my answer :)

Comment: @mt0000 I have just updated my answer with the solution. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I've added the `session.activate()` to the `InterfaceController` and since then, I get a reply from the Watch in the console, that the WCSession has been successfully activated. Unfortunately, still neither sendMessage nor transferUserInfo works, as the `session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo  userInfo:` OR `[...] didReceiveMessage message:` never runs on the Watch side, so I couldn't extract the dictionary/message I am trying to pass.

Comment: there are two delegate functions for `didReceiveMessage`, one of them has reply `replyHandler` as I mentioned in my answer. have you implemented both of them?

Comment: also, try to keep the refetence to WCSession object in both ViewController and InterfaceController